# silverlight datagrid to display local time

Tags: silverlight, datetime, datagrid, localtime

I bind date this way in silverlight datagrid, would it convert to local time?

```
Binding="{Binding aDate, StringFormat=dd/MMM/yyyy, Mode=OneWay}"
```

this doesn't seems to work for me. for example if user in Hongkong query data for '09-Aug-2013', server translate it to Universal Time as '08-Aug-2013' and return to client. but binding as above doesn't convert it back to '09-Aug-2013' still display as '08-Aug-2013'

Comment: What value does aDate contain? Local or UTC-Time? It seems that you assign a UTC-time value to aDate...(?)
Edit: Ah ok - server translate it to UTC. Ok. You have to use a second date (bDate) - convert the UTC time to local time and assign it to bDate.

Comment: You are missing a lot of details that are needed to help you further.  1) How are you transmitting the data from the server to the Silverlight client?  2) is `aDate` a `DateTime`? And if so, what `.Kind` is it?  3) Is the data *stored* in UTC? You say it is translated, but what is it originally?  4) Do you expect your client  to be working in *their* time zone? Or in some *other* time zone?  The more details you can provide, the better.  The actual binding to XAML is not very important.